# How can I move this button?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a login page. I need to move this button! How to do it?
I have attached the link to the problem.
[image]

```
     <form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
            <fieldset >
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
 
            <label for='username' >UserName:</label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />
 <br>
            <label for='password' >Password:</label>
            <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
 <br>
            <button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="login.php"> Login </button>
 
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

CSS:

```
    /*! HTML5 Boilerplate v4.3.0 | MIT License | http://h5bp.com/ */

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #222;
}

html {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

audio,
canvas,
img,
video {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

p {
  margin: 0px !important;  
}

.browsehappy {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

/* ===== Initializr Styles ==================================================
   Author: Jonathan Verrecchia - verekia.com/initializr/responsive-template
   ========================================================================== */

body {
    font: 16px/26px Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 5%;
}

/* ===================
    ALL: Orange Theme
   =================== */

.header-container {
    border-bottom: 20px solid #81ADDB;
}

.footer-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #81ADDB;
    height: 30px;
}

.header-container,
.main aside {
    background: #81ADDB;
    height: 30px;
}

.title {
    color: white;
}

/* ==============
    MOBILE: Menu
   ============== */

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 15px 0;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;

    color: white;
    background: #81ADDB;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:visited {
    color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* ==============
    MOBILE: Main
   ============== */

.main {
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.main article h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.main aside {
    color: white;
    padding: 0px 5% 10px;
}

.footer-container footer {
    color: #333;
    height: 20px;
}

/* ===============
    ALL: IE Fixes
   =============== */

.ie7 .title {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */

#login-container {
    border: 2px solid #efefef;
    width: 30%;
}
input {
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}












/* ==========================================================================
   Media Queries
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {

/* ====================
    INTERMEDIATE: Menu
   ==================== */

    nav a {
        float: left;
        width: 27%;
        margin: 0 1.7%;
        padding: 25px 2%;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    nav li:first-child a {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    nav li:last-child a {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

/* ========================
    INTERMEDIATE: IE Fixes
   ======================== */

    nav ul li {
        display: inline;
    }

    .oldie nav a {
        margin: 0 0.7%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

/* ====================
    WIDE: CSS3 Effects
   ==================== */

    .header-container,
    .main aside {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #aaa;
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #aaa;
                box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #aaa;
    }

/* ============
    WIDE: Menu
   ============ */

    .title {
        float: left;
    }

    nav {
        float: right;
        width: 38%;
    }

/* ============
    WIDE: Main
   ============ */

    .main article {
        float: left;
        width: 57%;
    }

    .main aside {
        float: right;
        width: 28%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1140px) {

/* ===============
    Maximal Width
   =============== */

    .wrapper {
        width: 1026px; /* 1140px - 10% for margins */
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */

.ir {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    *text-indent: -9999px;
}

.ir:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 150%;
}

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
    * {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    a,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }

    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }

    .ir a:after,
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
    a[href^="#"]:after {
        content: "";
    }

    pre,
    blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }

    tr,
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }

    @page {
        margin: 0.5cm;
    }

    p,
    h2,
    h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }

    h2,
    h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nL4Ka/2/

Without changing your HTML, I added the following CSS:

- I added a width to the input and label and made them float either on the left for the Labels and right for the Input tags in order to fill each form's row and to keep them separated

  ```
  #login input {
      margin: 10px 0;
      float: right;
      width: 60%;
  }
  #login label {
      width: 25%;
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      margin: 8px;
  }
  ```
- And finally I applied a float right to the Login button and the most important one, the **clear left**.

  ```
  #login button {
      clear: left;
      float: right;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position: absolute` to align the element like so:

```
fieldset {
    position: relative;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind buddy; Here is code:

```
input {
margin: 10px;
float: right;
position: relative;
clear: right;
}
```

Cheers,
Ashok

Answer (score -1):

i only ordered with table,tr,td tags

```
<form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>

           <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

        <label for='username' >UserName:</label>
        <input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for='password' >Password:</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>
            <button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="login.php"> Login </button>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>


        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

and you can add some style in your css

```
  fieldset {
    position: relative;
}

button {

    right: 0;
}
```